# Head menu loses CSS style

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When you're on this page: [Example page](https://www.dansinstituutwalkiers.be/lesschema-september/)

You'll see that "Agenda" has a blue background and "Lessen september – december 2017" is pink.

When you click on one of the other menu items, the submenu item keeps its pink color, but the head menu loses its blue background.

Is there a way to make the head-menu keep it's blueish background on every sub-menu item?

Here's two screenshots to clarify:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.gyazo.com/00f79ce1a3cb95d3f96cfea36dfadf80.png) ,
[Screenshot 2](https://i.gyazo.com/2c05ed3d24f9b223eb5e7291f69595a7.png)

**EDIT:**

In the end I learned that this was done via jQuery.  I wasn't aware of the information at this time. jQuery would append the correct classes to the html entities, this was derived from the URL.

Comment: The page you link to doesn't look anything like your description. Can you provide a [mcve] that does demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Could you explain where it doesn't look anything like the description? Because when I click the link, I see exactly what I described?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 CSS rules that are being applied depending on what is clicked. You need to review if one of them needs to be removed.

```css
ul.oi_header_menu_fixed>li>a {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.oi_header_menu_fixed>li.current_page_item>a,
.oi_header_menu_fixed>li.current_page_parent>a,
.oi_header_menu_fixed>li.current-menu-parent>a,
.oi_header_menu_fixed>li.current-menu-ancestor>a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I can see these two rules, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to figure out. My problem is that I want to keep the CSS style of my Head menu item (with the blue background color), no matter which sub menu item you're on. As it is now, I only see the blue background color on the first sub menu item.